# switching from built-in audio to usb-codec

Tags: recording, fl-studio

I'm using the free trial of FL Studio. When I go to options->audio settings->device... and change it from built-in input to usb-codec for my m-audio m-track solo, it doesn't use the usb-codec option.  It only uses the built in.  Like the signal of audio that comes in is from the built in, not from the m-audio box.

Comment: Sounds like the app is broken. Have you tried FL support?

Comment: It is hard to say something with such limited information. We do not know what your "m-audio box" is. Please give more information.

Comment: m-audio m-track solo; sorry

Comment: Do you have M-audio drivers installed? Are you using Windows Audio or ASIO?